# Check the User permission on a list item which has unique permission will show None if the user is added through office 365 group

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, administration, office-365-groups

I have a list item which has unique permission >> and we have created a new Office 365 group and add 6 members inside it >> then i assigned the Office 365 group to the list item with contribute permission >> but when i check one of the group members permissions on the list item, it gave me None.. although the user should have contribute on the list item through the Office 365 group.. is this a time issue since we created the group 15 minutes ago? or this is by design ?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I create a Microsoft 365 group with a member, I grant the Microsoft 365 group with contribute permission, then check the member's permission, it shows "None".

In my opinion, because you grant permission for an entire group, not each member, it is by design.

Comment: yes seems it is by design,,, but i noted if the user access the list item, then the Check Permission will show the correct permission level.. not sure how/why?

Comment: My guess is because accessing the list item caused the user to be added to the User Information List.

Comment: I agree with @Greg W.